# Cannot Install Oculus - Not Enough Disk Space

Tags: windows, installation, oculus

This post pertains to attempts to install the Oculus software (which is required for development with the Rift) that fail because there's not enough disk space when there in fact is.  A little research reveals that this has been a problem since the DK1 and has to do with dynamic disks and the way Oculus installer attempts to ensure that the drive is fast enough.

https://forums.oculusvr.com/community/discussion/34739/oculussetup-exe-says-not-enough-space-when-space-exists/p1

I hesitated to post this on Stack Overflow, however, I encounter this error when trying to setup a Dev machine for VR development with Oculus, and the solution is sufficiently obscure and not available in a single location yet, and I felt overall it makes sense for it to be here.

You can try going the route of creating a VHD on your dynamic disk, however, for me, even after doing that, the Oculus installer wasn't able to recognize a drive to install on.

I was in a position to reinstall Windows 10.  So, with a USB made with the latest Windows 10 installer, my drives were identified as dynamic and GPT and while I could reformat them I couldn't delete them or otherwise change them from dynamic using the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to go to the command prompt during Windows 10 installation (Shift-F10) and use "diskpart" command line utility to select the appropriate disk and clean it.  Like so:

```
>> diskpart
>> select disk <disk#>
>> clean
>> exit
```

Then I was able to really format the drive through the Windows 10 installation GUI and proceed as usual with the installation of Windows 10 and then Oculus.